# how can i package an electron app for linux?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have been using electron to make desktop application for a while now but still can't figure out how it can be packaged for all the available linux distributions

Answer (score 0):

For **ALL** linux distributions I have no idea. The way I make mine Linux Electron projects is just

```
npm install --save-dev electron-builder
```

add this to the root of my package.json

```
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.myname.appname",
    "asar": true,
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.developer-tools"
    }
  },
```

I make a `build` folder in the root and put

```
icon.icns
icon.ico
```

which I built from [this site](https://iconverticons.com/online/)

and then

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron-builder
```

it puts an .AppImage file in `dist`

more instructions [here](https://github.com/greggman/electron-hello-world)